Using pugixml and OpenXLSX in the same project results in a linker error
I have a CMake&C++ project where I prepared a condensed wrapper for pugixml. This wrapper is then linked to my io.lib library and works nicely on both ubuntu-22.04 and windows-latest.
I then added OpenXLSX library to be able to read/write excel *.xlsx files.
The problem (at least I think that is the problem?) is that according to the OpenXLSX readme, OpenXLSX also uses pugixml. This results in a linker error on windows machine :
2024-05-22T09:13:31.4230545Z pugixml.lib(pugixml.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: struct pugi::xml_node_struct * __cdecl pugi::xml_text::_data(void)const " (?_data@xml_text@pugi@@AEBAPEAUxml_node_struct@2@XZ) already defined in OpenXLSX.lib(XLCellValue.obj) [D:\a\wingdesigner\wingdesigner\build\apps\wingdesigner.vcxproj]

while it still compiles successfully on ubuntu-22.04.
My root CMakeLists.txt uses CPM to include both libraries
include(cmake/CPM.cmake)
CPMAddPackage("gh:troldal/OpenXLSX#ededa1e8398305d0983648d3e9f120ff7e228d2b")
CPMAddPackage("gh:zeux/pugixml@1.14")

and my io library uses both, therefore the io/CMakeLists.txt links both to target:
target_link_libraries(io PUBLIC pugixml spdlog::spdlog Eigen3::Eigen OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX)

Is there an elegant way to solve this issue?

Dynamic linking instead of static?

Unfortunately I do not know CMake and consequently do not use it, however in Windows using CodeBlocks / GCC (14.2) I wrote a small test using both pugixml.dll and OpenXLSX.dll (with static linking).
The program compiles and runs without linking problems. 
The OpenXLSX library has recently had major updates and I recommend downloading the development source from Github.
The xml file is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
<hello>Hello, world!</hello>
<value>42</value>
</sample>

The code is as follows:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <OpenXLSX.hpp>
#include <pugixml.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::string xmlfile = "sample.xml";
    const std::string xlsxfile = "sample.xlsx";

    pugi::xml_document xmldoc;
    OpenXLSX::XLDocument exceldoc;

    pugi::xml_parse_result result = xmldoc.load_file("sample.xml");

    // Verifiy if parsing gone well
    if (!result) {
        std::cout << "Error parsing: " << result.description() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // get nodes value

    auto root = xmldoc.child("sample");
    pugi::xml_node hello_node = root.child("hello");
    pugi::xml_node value_node = root.child("value");

    // Estracts values
    std::string  hello = hello_node.child_value();
    int value = std::atoi(value_node.child_value());

    // Creates the Excel file
    exceldoc.create("sample.xlsx", XLForceOverwrite);
    auto wks = exceldoc.workbook().worksheet("Sheet1");

    // Writes value to some cells
    wks.cell("A1").value() = hello;
    wks.cell("A2").value() = value;

    exceldoc.save();

    return 0;
}

